# How can I describe a nudge performed with my leg or foot?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When my hands are full, I'll often use my leg or foot to help me navigate my environment. For example, when I am loading the dishwasher, I'll use the top of my foot to shut it. I'll also use my knee and shin to open a self-closing door.

The problem is I have two young boys, and when they see me do this they try to emulate me. They'll shout "kick! kick!" and forcefully kick these things, which is undesirable. Right now I am struggling to find a good word to describe what I am doing that is different than kicking. Right now I call it a "nudge," but it doesn't feel appropriate in this context. This is especially true because they can still nudge an already closed dishwasher or open door when no additional nudge is needed.

What is a good word or phrase I can use to describe this type non-violent nudge that fulfills a specific goal?

Comment: It's still a nudge, even if you used your grocery bag instead of your hands or feet.

Comment: ...or a prod, perhaps.

Comment: In my Dad's immortal words 'I didn't kick the cat, I moved it with my foot.'